# How to exploit CSRF using HTML form to save data?

Tags: web-application, javascript, csrf

So I found a CSRF vulnerability on a website. The website is sending GET request to get user data and there is no protection. So using HTML I can get the data from the website if the user is logged in, but I can't save it to my website.

I can't use javascript XHR because of CORS. So is there any way to save the vulnerable website's json response through a HTML form in a separate file on my computer?

HTML code which just shows user data:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="myform" enctype='text/html' action="https://example.com/v3/user" method="GET"
    </form>
    <script>
      document.forms[0].submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it means it is exploitable, So Do you Think I should report this vulnerability to the website ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you concluded that it is exploitable from my statement *"the cross-origin attacker can __not__ get access to the servers response"*. Insecure CORS policies do seem to be here since you state that you cannot use XHR because of CORS. To say it more explicit: based on your information this can __not__ be exploited to read the servers response.

Answer (score 3):

When exploiting a CSRF vulnerability, you are changing the state of the server (i.e. writing). You are not stealing data (i.e. reading). The browsers same origin policy (SOP) is preventing you from reading the HTTP response.

It sounds like you found an endpoint with no CSRF protection, but all it does is returning sensitive data without changing the state of the server (like adding a user, deleting a record or whatever). That is not exploitable with CSRF.

You are talking about saving data in a file on *your* computer. An CSRF attack is executed on the victims computer. If you are somehow reading data and sending it to your computer, it's not a CSRF attack. CSRF may be part of it, but there must be something more going on.

I recommend you read up on CSRF attacks. [Here](https://medium.com/@charithra/introduction-to-csrf-a329badfca49) is a good article.

Comment: The article is written in bad English. It's not a good article then.

Comment: @postoronnim If you have a better suggestion, I'd be happy to edit.